# How to make versioning with Swagger and Spring Boot?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I've read a lot of StackOverflow questions, but there is no good solution for me. I'm searching for a way to document our API with a version number.

We have v1 and v2. So the best way is to generate 2 different swaggers.

The controllers are in different packages and for one version is one controller.

Is this possible with swagger? And how we can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use swagger groups. Check out this documentation: [Springfox Documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#swagger-group)